# Formatting Headers, Quotes, Titles

Tags: richtext, format

I've just updated to 2.5 and am now not able to see or find the text styling option in a text box. We use the formatting option across our site for different headers, quotes, etc. Am I missing something or is the feature gone?

Answer (score 3):

> If your Redactor config included a "formatting" value in the "buttons" array, you need to rename that to "format".

https://craftcms.com/help/redactor-ii-configs

Comment: Also, the format button tags have changed from"formattingtags" to "formatting",  or it won't work. Like:   
     formatting: ["p", "h2", "h3", "h4"]

Comment: @noregt Thanks for pointing that out! Just updated the support article.